# Trying to modify a method that opens a file to open specific file extentions in C#

Tags: c#, extension-methods, openfiledialog

I have a method that I copy over and over and again to choose a file and return a file name and I got sick of modifying it on a case by case basis so I've decided to go ahead and to write a few overloads for it that will cover most of the ways I use it.

This is the most basic overload:

```
    public void OpenFiles(out string path)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            path = ofd.FileName;
        else
            path = null;
        return;
    }
```

Sometimes, I want to specify a file extension or a set of file extensions and at first I was going to write a separate overload for each file type, but I want to write something more general where someone can use the method and in the overload choose one or many extensions that will limit what files they can open.

At first I started writing an overload like this:

```
    public void OpenFiles(string filter, out string path)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = filter;
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            path = ofd.FileName;
        else
            path = null;
    }
```

but this isn't quite the effect I am going for. Then I thought about writing an extension method like this:

```
public class Filters
{
    public string fileExtFilter(this ReturnFilePaths filePath, string filetype)
    {
        string txtFilter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
        string csvFilter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
        string xlsxFilter = "xlsx files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
        string xlsFilter = "xls files (*.xls)|*.xls";

        if (filetype == "csv")
            return csvFilter;
        else if (filetype == "txt")
            return txtFilter;
        else if (filetype == "xlsx")
            return xlsxFilter;
        else if (filetype == "xls")
            return xlsFilter;
        else
            return "All files (*.*)|*.*";
    }
}
```

but I know that this don't not line up with how I write my initial methods.Anyone have any suggestions or know of a library that already has something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is the filter you want, you could just make an method to build the filter string:

```
public string BuildFilterString(bool includeAllFiles, params string[] extensions)
{
    var filters = extensions.Select(ex => string.Format("{0} files (*.{0})|*.{0}", ex)); 
    string result = string.Join("|", filters);

    if (includeAllFiles)
    {
        result += result == string.Empty ? "All files (*.*)|*.*" : "|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    }

    return result;
}
```

You could then build a filter via:

```
filter = BuildFilterString(true, "csv", "xls", "xlsx");
```

Comment: Reed - no offense intended by my answer, just giving the OP another option. I like the simplicity of your answer. :-)

Comment: @Reed - Oh haha you are right Reed. Sorry I am still getting used to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You want to build the string for all the filter you want to pass to the open file dialog. There is an example of doing such a thing in a library called [FilterBuilder](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42085/FilterBuilder). The article has the source code and over 100+ popular file types already in the library.

Also, the syntax for building the filter string is a call to the `FilterBuilder` object's `Add()` method. Reed's solution will work, but will become cumbersome for scenarios where the number of file types gets large, because each type is a argument of the `BuildFilterString()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My ultimate goal is to create something that just asks for some or no extensions and returns a file path or a list of file paths. I will check out FilterBuilder, but I think I may try to incorporate Reed's method into what I have written so far.

Comment: Could you explain this line though?

`result += result == string.Empty ? "All files (*.*)|*.*" : "|All files (*.*)|*.*";` I think it is something like if result is empty return the first, if result is not empty return the second?

Comment: @Adam You might want to have commented on my post ;)  That's because you can just do `BuildFilterString(true)` (to just get All Files), and that's prevent it from putting a | at the beginning of the filter.

Comment: @Adam - LOL, yeah what Reed said! :-) That is the ternary operator, it literally translates to `concatenate to the current value of result the value All files (*.*)|*.* if the result is currently empty; otherwise concatenate the value |All files (*.*)|*.*`. In simpler words, it only appends the All files option with a pipe if it is not the only filter in the parameters list.